# Limiting concurrent Ubuntu session not working!

Tags: ssh, login, session

I am trying to limit my user's concurrent logins. Every user should be able to have a limited number of simultaneous ssh connections to my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. To `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, I added `session  required  pam_limits.so`
2. To `/etc/security/limits.conf`, I added the following:

   - `username hard  maxlogins  1`

     - I also tried:

       - `username -  maxlogins  1`
       - `* -  maxlogins  1`
3. In `sshd_config` `UsePAM yes` was not commented by default
4. I then ran `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`
5. Finally, I ran `reboot server`

But still, I could do login with ssh to my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server through several clients!

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry I just doubled check it, It's a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server, Thanks for your comment